# Can I split character vector based on position in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, split, identifier

This is my first post so all tips for posting are helpful :)

I want to merge two data frames with the same person-IDs, but the identifier is slightly (but systematically) different from one another.

- in df `A` the `ID` is: <3 digits>
- in df `B` the `ID` is: -<3 digits>

See example below:

```
A_ID <- c("A123", "B213", "C421", "C312")
A_score <- c(8,10,9,10)
A <- data.frame(A_ID, A_score)
colnames(A) <- c("ID", "A_score")


B_ID <- c("A-123", "B-213", "C-421", "C-312")
B_score <- c(2,10,9,10)
B <- data.frame(B_ID, B_score)
colnames(B) <- c("ID", "B_score")
```

The problem is that because of the `-` in the middle of df `B` identifiers, these dfs won't merge.

What i want to achieve is to merge (`fulljoin`) the dfs to form columns: `ID` | `A_score` | `B_score`.

I tried converting the character vector to strings and then split the `ID` (`A`) at characterposition 2 after the letter, add a `-` and then paste and convert back to character vector. But i feel this is probably not the most efficient and easy way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `gsub()` to clean the second id variable and then merge the dataframes in a one data pipeline. Here the code using `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
NewA <- A %>% full_join(B %>% mutate(ID=gsub('-','',ID)))
```

Output:

```
    ID A_score B_score
1 A123       8       2
2 B213      10      10
3 C421       9       9
4 C312      10      10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sub` to ge rid of `-` and then `merge`:

```
B$ID <- sub("-", "", B$ID)
merge(A, B, "ID")
    ID A_score B_score
1 A123       8       2
2 B213      10      10
3 C312      10      10
4 C421       9       9
```